# Error in Xamarin: `Could not find part of the path play-services-basement-10.0.1.aar`

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I have been working on an android app where you can send push notifications with firebase. But when I build the app, I get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\playservices-10.0.1\playservicesbasement\play-services-basement-10.0.1.aar'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarRestore.LoadResource(String resourceFullPath, String assemblyName)
   at Xamarin.Build.Download.BaseXamarinBuildResourceRestore.MergeResources(IAssemblyResolver resolver, String originalAsmPath, String mergedAsmPath, String assemblyName, List`1 resourceItems)    message
```

I already tried to delete the content of these folders and rebuilding:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin.*
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips
```

I cant really find anything about this problem on the internet, so it would be great if someone could help me resolve this issue.

Comment: I Have the same issue... any progress on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: @Michael I started using android studio. All the errors I previously had with xamarin is gone in android studio. Android studio makes it MUCH easier.